# Pause vertical scroll while div scrolls horizontally, at the end of horizontal scroll continue scrolling vertically

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, parallax, horizontalscrollview

There is a group of images vertically stacked in a `<div class="container">` that has `overflow-y: auto`. After first image, there is a `<div class="info">` which contains some text that is wider than that parent `div` and needs to scroll horizontally (`overflow-x: auto').

The idea is to have that `container` scroll vertically until the `info` hits `container` top edge. At that point vertical scroll stops and the `info` starts it horizontal scroll. After it hits the end, the vertical scroll of the parent `container` continues 'till the end of its content.

It should work the same on scroll up.

I've tried few options, jQuery, parallax, pure CSS, but nothing worked at the end.

Here's the codepen example: https://codepen.io/front-man/pen/mQqvPb

Comment: Do you want the vertical scroll scrolls the `info` horizontal when it hits the top edge or just  disable  the vertical scroll until you scroll horizontal the `info`?

Comment: Yes, let's say that is the hitting the top edge. The `info` will also be full height so when it hits top edge of the `container` it should start scrolling horizontally using mouse wheel.

Answer (score 2):

First let's do a trick to handle horizontal scroll using vertical scroll with CSS only, the idea is rotate the container -90deg and the content 90deg and use the default stuff to scroll like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 410px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  * {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

.info {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;  
  font-size: 40px;
  
  transform: rotate(-90deg)  translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: right top;
  
  overflow-y: auto;  //this will be add using js
} 

.info p {
  transform: rotate(90deg)  translateX(137px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus aspernatur reprehenderit placeat facere ut nam molestias nobis deleniti alias.
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you only use this, when you scroll down hard you can pass the `.info` and it will not take the focus to scroll itself so with js you can stop the default scroll when its top is less than the screen top and set the scroll's position to the element position, then activate the horizontal scroll of the `.info` (note that I do not have it activated in the CSS) when it finish deactivate the horizontal scroll and will continue scrolling vertically:

```js
var originalelementTop = $(".info").offset().top;
function myFunction() {
  var $info = $(".info");
  
  var elementTop = $info.offset().top;
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  var newScrollTop = $info.scrollTop(),
      width = $(".info p").outerWidth() + 20,
      scrollWidth = $(".info p").get(0).scrollWidth; 
  
  if (elementTop <= viewportTop && scrollWidth - newScrollTop != width){
      $info.css("overflow-y", "auto");
      $(".container").scrollTop(originalelementTop);
  } else {
    $info.css("overflow-y", "hidden");
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 410px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  * {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

.info {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;  
  font-size: 40px;
  
  transform: rotate(-90deg)  translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.info p {
  transform: rotate(90deg)  translateX(137px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" onscroll="myFunction()">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" alt="">
  <div class="info">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus aspernatur reprehenderit placeat facere ut nam molestias nobis deleniti alias.
    </p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" alt="">
</div>
```

Do something similar for when you scroll up.

Note: I use fixed values only to show the general idea, adapt it to your context. I hope I've helped you.